# Postfix dovecot remote mail client connection

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am stuck in the following issue for like hours. Hopefully someone can help me out this one :x..

I set up a mail server to receive and send e-mails. receiving by imap.

The problem I am facing is as follow.

On the webserver I created two mail account, I am able to send messages to each other by using mailx or telnet (directly on the server). Now I want to add these mail accounts to my mail client at my desktop PC. I did this but I am not able to send any e-mail or receive any e-mails sending from in the client.

When I make use of xmail or telnet mailing I directly get a message in the imap account configured at my mail client (desktop pc).

I put open all the needed ports for mailing;

```
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

Please any suggestions so I can try to figure this thing out.

Hope mu information can tell something to you, else let me know what
you would know or needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like something wrong with postfix and dovecot configs. I can't tell more without that configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information from your side, I can only give you some basic clues.

It looks like your mail service is somewhere limited to be accessible only from/to localhost. Depending on the server OS your server is running on, it can be set quite restrictive by default, allowing only local access (127.0.0.1).

1. Check your firewall configs in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, e.g.:

   `:USER_IMAP - [0:0]
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 --syn -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 --syn -j ACCEPT
   :USER_POP3 - [0:0]
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 --syn -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 --syn -j ACCEPT`
2. Check SELinux status with `sestatus` (with Status disabled / permissive you can go ahead)
3. Check your Postfix config. Make sure it is configured correctly for what domains to receive/send mails for (e.g. default is to receive mail for the machine itself only), 
   so for receiving Mail worldwide check your 
   /etc/postfix/main.cf:

   `mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain`
4. Also check your Dovecot config in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`, e.g. for IPv4 it should be set to

   `listen = *`

   With `dovecot -n` you can check how Dovecot is finally set up.
   Also check if all needed ports are also listening:
   `netstat -tulpn |grep LISTEN`

Hope that helps, Megodin